# Verificar frequência de registros na tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, filtro, sql-server-express

Tenho uma tabela onde estão salvos todos os serviços realizados em diversos carros. A chave é a placa do carro.
Um carro pode ter mais de um serviço realizado ao dia. E para cada serviço realizado é criado um novo id de serviço, mesmo que seja para o mesmo carro.

Preciso filtrar os 100 carros mais frequentes e não consigo, pois, está impreciso por salvar um id para cada serviço.

Ex: 
carro aaa1234 nos dias 01,02,03 fez 3 tipos de serviços por dia. 
carro bbb4321 nos dias 01,02,03 fez 1 tipo de serviço por dia.

Se estou certo, na minha query, tá acusando que o carro aaa1234 é o mais frequente. Sendo que não queria contabilizar por quantidade de serviço, mas, por frequência.

Não sou tão hábil com querys e não consigo fugir desse escopo:

```
SELECT count(placa), placa
  FROM [producao].[dbo].[servicos_teste]
  group by placa
  order by COUNT(placa) DESC
```

Comment: é isso mesmo, porém você já conta a placa uma vez, não precisa repetir o comando apenas dê um alias para o COUNT e ordene por ele:

SELECT 
             count(placa) AS qtd, 
             placa 
FROM [producao].[dbo].[servicos_teste] 
GROUP BY  placa 
ORDER BY qtd DESC

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considerando-se a existência de coluna que indique a data de entrada do veículo na oficina, uma opção é contar o número de datas de entrada diferentes, para cada placa.

```
-- código #1 v2
SELECT top (100) placa, count(distinct data_entrada) as Frequência
  FROM [producao].[dbo].[servicos_teste]
  group by placa
  order by Frequência desc;
```

Sugiro que a cada entrada de veículo na oficina seja aberta uma ordem de serviço. Cada OS poderá conter um ou mais serviços a realizar no veículo. Altere então a estrutura da tabela servicos_teste para conter coluna com numeração de ordem de serviço (OS). Desta forma fica mais confiável, pois basta contar a quantidade de OS abertas para cada placa.